# RxJava2 - last successful Single from concat

Tags: java, observable, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have N Single sources and I want to concat these and get the latest successful Single. For ex:

DB Single:

**--[A]--|->**

API Single:

**---X--->**

Single.concat(DB, API):

**--[A]--|->**

Otherwise:

DB Single:

**--[A]--|->**

API Single:

**--[B]--|->**

Single.concat(DB, API):

**--[B]--|->**

Is that possible? I read the documentation but I didn't find anything like "lastSuccessfullOrError()" method. I tried "elementAt","lastOrError" and others but their behavior is not what I'm looking for

Thank you

Comment: If you have a few sources, you can have a look at [Single.onErrorResumeNext(Single)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#onErrorResumeNext-io.reactivex.Single-) and just chain up sources.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid this solution because implies the execution of API first and DB then, right? I'd like to execute DB first (which is faster, of course) and then try to retrieve updated data from API. Consider that I did a simplified example with 2 sources, but I'd like to find a generic solution valid for N sources

Comment: Why would it? put the DB `Single` first, then apply `onErrorResumeNext(API)`. Also there is no standard operator that keeps falling back to more than one source; you'd need a custom operator.

Comment: Why should I apply onErrorResumeNext to DB? I'm not following you. DB has data, so it won't go on error state. I just want to emit data from DB, because I know that contains data and it is very fast, then I want to emit API data if API source is successful, otherwise just complete the stream instead of throwing an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved as follows:

```
public static <T> Single<T> latestSuccess(Single<T>... sources) {
     return Single.defer(() -> {
         AtomicReference<T> last = new AtomicReference<T>();
         return Observable.fromArray(sources)
             .concatMap(source ->
                  source.doOnSuccess(last::lazySet)
                  .toObservable()
                  .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
             )
             .ignoreElements()
             .andThen(Single.fromCallable(() -> {
                 if (last.get() == null) {
                     throw new NoSuchElementException();
                 }
                 return last.get();
             }));
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way that, in my opinion, is a good solution is using the [**`skip`**](https://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/skip.html) operator:

> suppress the first n items emitted by an Observable

[image: skip operator flow]

Give the number of items that has been passed through `concat` and subtract 1 to let the last one pass through.

```kotlin
val listOfObservables = localChanges.map { myList ->
    pushChangeToServer(myList)
}

Observable.concat(listOfObservables)
    // Get only the latest:
    .skip(localChanges.size - 1)
    .map { lastResult ->
        return@map lastResult.data
    }
```